# php system() function cannot use

Tags: php

I just use the document example code to test.

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    $last_line = system('ls', $retval);

    echo '
    </pre>
    <hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
    <hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```

But on the result is 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfg5I.png)

And I remove the system in disable_function of php.ini.
But it is still no use.

Comment: what is `$retval` ?

Comment: What's with the `。` in `echo '<pre>';。`?

Comment: just input error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three key reasons why your code is probably not working:

1. There is an illegal character in your code. Chances are, errors are disabled, however PHP is halting. Remove `。` on the first line of your PHP.
2. If you are on Windows, `ls` is not a valid command - it only works on *nix systems (Linux, Unix / macOS). You'll have to replace `ls` with `dir`.
3. Finally, if it still does not work, you must have not enabled the use of `system` correctly. Double-check that `disable_functions` in your `php.ini` file does not have `system` listed, and then **restart your Apache server**.